# Screen orientation of view pager

Tags: android

I am using webview to show number of HTML pages with the help of view pager.
In portrait mode I use to show one web view and in landscape mode two web views.
When I rotate device from portrait to landscape the view is updated but page content size is portrait one (i.e-page size is big like in portrait mode) for the first webview again when I rotate device from landscape to portrait view is updated but page content size is small as in landscape mode but when I move to other pages the page size is wrap content to the web view.

Comment: can you add screenshots?

Comment: you need at least 15 rep to add photos.

Comment: I can not find any option to add screenshots.Can you help @ApurvaKolapkar

Comment: I assume you set layout_width and layout_height to match_parent. If you use wrap_content instead, this may explain the issue.

Comment: I used wrap content for both width and height @cyanide